# Volume limited by $z=2-x^2-y^2$ and $z^2 = x^2 + y ^2$ (two ways)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to compute the volume limited by  $z=2-x^2-y^2$ and $z^2 = x^2 + y ^2$ and $z\geq 0$. I plot the region with Desmos 3d. I'm not interested in the result, just if I present correctly the triple integral.
Changing into cylindrical coordinates $(r , \theta , z)$, the equations reads as
$$  z\leq 2-x^2-y^2 \Rightarrow r \leq \sqrt{2-z} $$
$$ z^2 \geq x^2 + y^2 \Rightarrow r \leq z $$
Obviously, $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and, finally, $0\leq z \leq 2$ (this is clear from the plot). So my final answer will be:
$$ V = \int_{\theta = 0 } ^{2\pi} \int _{z=0}^2 \int_{r = 0}^{\min \lbrace z , \sqrt{2-z}  \rbrace } r \ drdzd\theta = \int_{\theta = 0 } ^{2\pi} \int _{z=0}^1 \int_{r = 0}^{ z} r \ drdzd\theta   +     \int_{\theta = 0 } ^{2\pi} \int _{z=1}^2 \int_{r = 0}^{\sqrt{2-z}  } r \ drdzd\theta $$
**Is this correct?**

Another question, without a change of coordinates, would be
$$  V = \int_{x=-2}^2 \int_{y=-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} \int _{z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{2-x^2-y^2} 1\ dzdydx$$
**Am I right?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the second way, $x$ takes values from $-2$ to $2$. For each value of $x$, $y$ goes from $-\sqrt{2-x^2}$ to $\sqrt{2-x^2}$. So in the case where $x=2$, $y$ goes from $-\sqrt{-2}$ to $\sqrt{-2}$?

Comment: Oh its true... I guess I've to separate into two differents region (as happens with cylindrical coordinates). Can you help me with that?

Comment: I think I already solve it, thank you anyway!